# How to redirect page after click on Ok button and cancel button on sweet alert?

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

I want to click the 'Ok' button then redirect to one page and click on 'Cancel' button and redirect to another page. How can I do that?

```
 function saveCase() {
      if (recordedFullSymptoms.length != 0 && cust_preferenceFile.patient.patientId == 0) {
       swal({
          text: "You can save the case by selecting or creating new patient.",
          buttons: true,
          confirmButtonText: "Ok",
          showCancelButton: true,
          closeOnCancel: true
       }).then(function() {
          if(okay) {
           alert(1);
            getPartialView('PatientList', this);
          }else{
            getPartialView('RepertoryList', this)
          }         
     })
    }
   else
     {
        swal("Please select atleast one symptom to save case.");
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a second function to `.then()`.

```
swal(...)
.then(function(){ //Ok button action

}, function(){ //Cancel button action

})
```

Comment: any other solution